# /execute as - Failed to execute error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[Public Server - v1.10 - Vanilla]

I have a chain of commands that I'm running, which includes a command block that increments an armor stand's scoreboard value (used as a counter) when a player is with a specific set of scoreboard values is within a 5 block radius. If I stand at the command block while the player stands there, and change it between Chain/Always Active to Impulse/Always Active (back and forth), the command will eventually execute. Otherwise, the error I get is this:

```
Failed to execute 'scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Counter] Count 1' as playername
```

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
execute @a[score_param1_min=1,score_param1=1,score_param2_min=1,score_param2=1,score_counter_min=0,score_counter=0] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,name=ASCounter] counter 1
```

Changing the command block from Conditional to Unconditional has not made a difference, and I can confirm that the player is standing in the right spot at the right time.

I also tried changing the command block to a Repeating/Always Active, and no difference either.

I'm at a loss, so any help would be really appreciated. I don't want to remove the /execute as because that could cause some issues for other players down the road if the conditions were just right, and the command needs to be run reliably, or also major potential issues down the road.

Comment: If you run `scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Counter] counter 1` in chat by itself, do you get any error messages? Make sure you have an ArmorStand called `Counter`, and that it's in loaded chunks.

Comment: I think that the cmd bloxk thinks that "@e[type=ArmorStand,name=ASCounter] counter 1" is the name of the armour stand

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier That's not correct. His syntax is fine. The only ways the command itself can fail are if the armor stand doesn't exist or the "counter" objective doesn't exist.

Comment: @Skylinerw The armor stand and the scoreboard objective exist and I can confirm that the player is in the right spot (within 1 block, actually). I'm using an alt account to test. And the command does execute eventually if I change it to impulse/always active and back a few times.

Comment: @theBeaks An Impulse block is intended to only activate a single time. You should be using an unconditional Repeating block instead.

Comment: @Skylinerw Yes, it was just to test that the command actually worked. Me standing there to activate it isn't a feasible solution. It's supposed to be a chain block (it's about 4 blocks in on a chain of commands that runs in a clock). Basically, the command and the scoreboards and the conditions all check out each time, it just gives an error 70% of the time.

Comment: You should include the other commands you're using then, as they are very likely a contributor to the issue.

Comment: @Skylinerw They're conditional and I've stopped any commands that run after this one. They just do things like tp the player, set a scoreboard value, tp again, set scoreboard value. I've tested manually that the scoreboard values are set correctly when the player gets to the armor stand, and with the proceeding blocks all being conditional on the ones before executing successfully, I wouldn't be getting this far if they were failing.

Comment: @theBeaks Well we can't diagnose the issue with a command that is syntactically correct. We need all pieces of the puzzle. A screenshot of the clock in question would also be helpful. Have you also tried what colorfusion stated?

Comment: @colorfusion Yes, it runs ok. The commands are being run in spawn and I have 1 player standing to check the execution and 1 standing at the armor stand (alt account), so the chunks are definitely loaded. Even if I remove the /execute @ portion, the command runs ok, and if I instead remove the command following the /execute @ and put something like /say test, that runs ok (in other words both sides of the command work ok, no typos, scoreboards check out). And the command itself will execute about 30% of the time, just not most of the time.

Comment: @theBeaks Is the time (e.g: `[13:01:37]`) before the error message updating? If you set the command block to repeat and the objective to display in the siderbar, what do you see happening to the ArmorStand's score? What happens if you change `/say test` to `/say test @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Counter]`?

Comment: @colorfusion The time stamp shows the recent time executed (ie not from 20 minutes ago and it is trying to run it) and a score updates every so many tries. I was able to resolve it by breaking it into 2 commands, first using the parameters to add a tag, and then executing the second half of the original command by executing as a player with that tag. It seems as though the original command with all the parameters was just too much for it to handle reliably.

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely happening is that you don't have an armor stand named ASCounter. The best way to test what is actually happening is by doing the command separate from the execute, so 
`/scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,name=ASCounter] counter 1`
Then it will tell what is happening wrong.